# CiviEvent generates invalid link

Tags: wordpress, civievent

**What I have:**

1. test setup `mysite.com` using newest WP 6.3.2 and newest CiviCRM 5.66.0
2. CiviEvent: several events.
3. SearchKit: a search that gives me the results I want.
   One column has a link with the path `civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=[id]`
4. Form Builder: a form to hold the results from the search.
5. WordPress: a page that contains the shortcode with my search: `[civicrm component="afform" name="afsearchFoo"]`

**Problem: event link is broken:**

- The link given in step 3 above as `civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=10`
  **should** become: `https://mysite.com/civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=10`
  **actually** becomes: `https://mysite.com/courses/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=10`
- Notice that `/` changed to `%2F`, and
- Notice that the path includes the page slug (`/courses/`) where the shortcode is embedded.

**What I want:**

- The link should not be URLencoded and appended. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the event link path to the relative path
`civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=[id]`, use the absolute path
`https://mysite.com/civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=[id]`.